# Expanding an array to represent an index as many times as the magnitude of original value

Tags: java, arrays

Example: expand(new int[]{3, 2, 5}) -> {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}
I am trying to have it make a a new array to print the index of say 3, 3 times. So 3 would be 0,0,0.

```
public static int[] expand(int[] input) {
    int c = 0;
    int[] myArray = new int[sum(input)];
    if(input.length == 0){
        return new int[0];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        int a = input[i];
        for(int j = c; j < a; j++) {
            c += j;
            myArray[j] = i;

        }
    }

    return myArray;
}
```

Currently this only partially works and I cant seem to figure out how to go through the full array properly. In addition, index zero seems to get skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close!  It seems that you just need to modify your nested for-loop slightly:

```
for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
    myArray[c++] = i;
}
```

Seeing as you're using `c` to keep track of the current index, this simply sets the element at index `c` to `i` and increments `c`.  You can also remove `a` and use `input[i]` in place of it.

**Note**: It is easier to start `j` from `0` rather than from `c`.

Comment: Thank you!! I knew I was close but coudnt quite figure out what I was missing, this makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

## Functional method

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        int[] items = expand(new int[]{3, 2, 5});
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(items));
    }
    public static int[] expand(int[] input) {
        return IntStream.range(0, input.length)
                .flatMap(p -> IntStream.generate(() -> p).limit(input[p]))
                .toArray();
    }
}
```

This makes a stream of the index, and for each item takes that many of the index, putting all of them into an array